# Can I call a single row function query inside of a DBMS_OUTPUT statement?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

How can I output the results of a single row function using `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE`?

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
  'Comma seperated list of columns: ' || (SELECT WM_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME) FROM USER_CONS_COLUMNS)
);
```

*This is being called inside of a stored procedure.*

Answer (score 1):

No you can't.

You need to add an extra layer - a variable where the result set of the SQL query will be bind. PL/SQL has a special constructs for that. The construct applicable in this case is `select into`. Please see [Query Result Set Processing](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/static.htm#LNPLS00603) from [the fine manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/toc.htm) for more details.

Your example won't compile:

```
begin
  dbms_output.put_line((select dummy from dual));
end;
/
```

But will result a PLS-00103:

```
  dbms_output.put_line((select dummy from dual));
                        *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-06550: line 2, column 25:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of the following:
( - + case mod new not null <an identifier>
<a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable>
continue avg count current exists max min prior sql stddev
sum variance execute forall merge time timestamp interval
date <a string literal with character set specification>
<a number> <a single-quoted SQL string> pipe
<an alternatively-quoted string literal with character set specification>
<an alternat
ORA-06550: line 2, column 49:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:
. ( ) , * % & = - + < / > at in is mod remainder not rem
<an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
like4 likec between || multiset mem
```

A working example of `select into`:

```
declare
  v_dummy varchar2(32767);
begin
  -- the select statement can be arbitrary complex as long as it returns
  -- only one single row with a single column
  select dummy into v_dummy from dual;
  dbms_output.put_line(v_dummy);
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define variables and store the selected values as shown in the following code block

```
DECLARE
   v_wm_concat user_cons_columns.column_name%TYPE;

BEGIN
   SELECT WM_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME) FROM USER_CONS_COLUMNS INTO v_wm_concat
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Comma seperated list of columns: '|| v_wm_concat);
```